# JavaScript and the history.back() method

Tags: javascript

I want that if a user come on my homepage www.example.com from an external website an alert will be showed... but if the user come from an internal page of my website then the alert will not be showed.

I think history.back() method is useful in my case but I don't know how to use it for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cases will hide the referer, such as a bookmark to your site

This will work in most cases

```js
console.log(document.referrer)
if (document.referrer.indexOf(location.host) == -1) {
  document.write("Welcome to my site")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an optional http header that is called "referer", that I've used to detect where a call is coming from.

[W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14)